# Angular material table - this._elementRef is undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material

i was trying to use angular [material table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) and I found the following error:

```
    ERROR TypeError: "this._elementRef is undefined"
    ERROR CONTEXT
```

on the following line:

```html
    <mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="example-table"
               matSort matSortActive="created" matSortDisableClear      matSortDirection="desc">
```

I've noticed that when I remove the mat-table tag the error disappears.

> note: My app module is already importing MatTableModule

Here is my entire table code:

html

```html
    (...)

    <mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="example-table"
           matSort matSortActive="created" matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="desc">
      <!-- CRM Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="crm">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>CRM</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.crm}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- CPF Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="cpf">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>CPF</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.cpf}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="especializacao">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Especialização</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.especializacao}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Nome Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="nome">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear></th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.nome}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Telefone Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="telefone">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear></th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.telefone}}</td>
      </ng-container>


      <!-- Data nascismento Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="data_de_nascimento">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear></th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.data_de_nascimento}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </mat-table>

    (...)
```

js

```js
  // (...)

  data: MedicData[] = [];

  // (...)

  export interface MedicData {
    crm: string;
    cpf: string;
    especializacao: string;
    nome: string;
    telefone: string;
    data_de_nascimento: string;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is causing the exact error, but one thing I notice is that you are using the directive `mat-table` as the element name `<mat-table></mat-table>`. This is perfectly fine, but then you use the element names `<td></td>` instead of `<mat-cell></mat-cell>` etc. A `<td>` and `<tr></tr>` can't exist without a parent `<table>`, so it is most likely causing problems.

Comment: I'd also add that `datasource` within a `<mat-table>` should not be binded to the data array directly. you should do it like this instead: `data = new MatTableDataSource<MedicData>(dataArray)`

Comment: It's _technically_ okay to use an array as a datasource, but I agree using a MatTableDataSource is a far better option.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the target in `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

and to use [polyfills](https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/webcomponentsjs) like this:

```
import '@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min';
import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter';
```